# Filter with a particular constant date which is in between two column dates - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DF which has to be joined with a condition and the condition includes a date which needs to be in between two column dates

```
DF.joinWith(DF1,"21-02-2012" between DF.StartDate and DF1.EndDate)
```

- above code is a pseudo code how do i write the same in spark scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use literal:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.lit

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)

DF.join(DF1, lit("21-02-2012").between(DF("StartDate"), DF1("EndDate")))
```

Comment: If need to use any column value as filter condition, use like this `df2.as('df2).join(df1.as('df1), $"df1.Date".between($"df2.StartDate ", $"df2.EndDate"))`